# The SQL version used is not compatible with data type 'datetime2'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm using Entity Framework 4 with an MVC3 application to access data.

My SQL server version is SQL Server 2005.

When trying to save data, I get this error:

```
The SQL version used is not compatible with data type 'datetime2'.
```

Can someone explain what this bug is and how to fix it?

I never declared a property to be of type datetime2 and in act I never even heard of this data type before today.

After some Googling around I found somewhere that suggested I change the token of my .edmx file to use 2005:

```
<Schema ... ProviderManifestToken="2005" ...>
```

Yet this error is still firing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you rebuild the EF project after making that change? Try a Clean+Build. Somehow EF must be thinking that is working with SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime2 is only available on SqlServer 2008 or later

```
DATETIME2 is introduced in SQL Server 2008
```

You can change what you want on your "client" application, if the server does not supported it will not work.